# Exercise with matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

**A)** For which $a,b$ is the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0\\ 
b & b
\end{bmatrix}$ invertible?

**B)** Calculate $A^{1000}$ where $A$ is the above matrix with $a=1$ and $b=2$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

**A)** $$\begin{vmatrix}
a & 0\\ 
b & b
\end{vmatrix} \neq 0 \Rightarrow ab \neq 0 \Rightarrow a \neq 0 \text{ and } b \neq 0$$

**B)** $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$
How can I calculate $A^{1000}$??

Is it maybe  $$A^n=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
2 \cdot n & 2^n
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: why do you think it is that? if you tried say for 3 cases and think that is the case, prove it by induction.

Comment: wow a billion answers to an easy question...

Answer (score 4):

You may prove by induction that

$A^n=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
2^{n+1}-2 & 2^n
\end{bmatrix}$

but that's out of the blue.

---

Otherwise, notice that $A=I_2+\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Notice that $\forall n, \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^n=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

And apply Newton binomial theorem (you're allowed to since $I_2$ commutes with any matrix).

$A^{1000}=I_2+ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\sum_{k=1}^{1000} \binom{1000}{k}$

Answer (score 4):

**A)** looks good

**B)** Your approach to find a formula for $A^n$ is good. Try to prove by induction that$$A^n=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^i & 2^n
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix is diagonalizable, because u have 2 different eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=2$. Then [you find an invertible matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#How_to_diagonalize_a_matrix) $S$, such that $SAS^{-1}=D$ with a diagonal matrix D, which contains your eingenvalues:

Now we obtain the following:

$A^{1000}=(S^{-1}DS)^{1000}=S^{-1}DS*S^{-1}DS*....*S^{-1}DS=S^{-1}D^{1000}S$ (Because $S^{-1}S=I$).

But $D^{1000}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 2^{1000}  \\  \end{pmatrix}$. Then it follows that : $A^{1000}=S^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 2^{1000}  \\  \end{pmatrix} S$

Comment: it is certainly not diagonalisable, because it is already in (a possible) Jordan normal form and clearly it is not diagonal.

Comment: Thats wrong! If it where in jordan normalform, then there where 2 times "1". It is diagonalizable. See Wolfram Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C2%7D%7D. The fact that is has 2 different eigenvalues is sufficient.

Comment: point! (btw i didnt give the downvote), somebody needs to revise linear algebra